# Issue installing ND_JPEG component in Rave 5/Delphi 7

Tags: delphi

I received a new laptop at work (Windows 10 Version 1909 build 18363.1379) and have to install Delphi 7 (yes, I know it's outdated - no, there's no chance of updating to a newer version of Delphi) which I have successfully done.  However some of our code makes use of Rave reports with the Nevrona JPEG component (ND_JPEG50.bpl) which I have tried (quite unsuccessfully) to install.  Originally, the component would not install and gave an error about having an invalid entry point.  I was able to address that issue by compiling the .dpk file and then clicking "Install" which installed the component into Delphi 7 (but not RAVE).  When I went into Rave and attempted to install the package (which does exist in the location specified) I got the following error (quotes are in the error)

"A class named TRaveGraphicImage already exists" occurred while registering package "C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi7\Projects\Bpl\ND_JPEG50.bpl", unit "NDCsJPEG"

I then Removed the "Rave Graphics Components" packages and was able to add the ND_JPEG50.bpl in Rave.  However, when I restarted RAVE (as directed by RAVE), I get the same error as above.  After clicking Ok, I then I get the following error:

Exception EInvalidOperation in module visualclx70.bpl at 0008230C.
Cannot focus a disabled of invisible window (MainForm).

and then Rave goes into not responding mode and I have to kill it.

I have tried:

1. Uninstalling / re-installing D7 (as myself) several times
2. Uninstalling / re-installing D7 (as admin) a couple times
3. Running D7 / Rave as myself numerous times
4. Running D7 / Rave as admin numerous times.

It should be noted that when I run D7 as admin our home-grown components (accessed via the LAN) do not load (I believe that, for whatever reason, the admin privilege does not have LAN access) so I would prefer to NOT have to run D7 as admin.

I don't know if I have not installed Delphi 7 correctly (it seems unlikely since the rest of D7 is working just fine, but stranger things have happened with older programs) or if there's something with the latest version of Windows that either prevents Delphi 7/Rave 5 from working right or if there is some "magic" that I have yet to divine to get this working.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Edit:

If I run D7 as normal (not as admin) I am unable to get into Rave - it continues to give me the error about TRaveGraphicImage.  I have edited the Rave.ini file and removed the ND_JPEG50.bpl package and still get the error.  However, if I run D7 as admin, Rave comes up fine - but with a bunch of warnings about the home-grown components not loading.

If this provides any value, here is the contents of my Rave.ini file:

```
[Packages]
Rave Graphics Components=C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi7\Rave5\RvGraphics50.bpl
Rave Barcode Components=C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi7\Rave5\RvBarcode50.bpl
Rave Standard Components=C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi7\Rave5\RvStandard50.bpl
Rave Report Components=C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi7\Rave5\RvReport50.bpl
Rave Language Engine=C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi7\Rave5\RvEngine50.bpl
Rave Delphi Syntax Compiler=C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi7\Rave5\RvCompiler50.bpl
Rave Design-time Library=C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi7\Rave5\RvDesign50.bpl

[History]
ActiveProject=
Project0=Project1.rav
Project1=
Project2=
Project3=
Project4=
Project5=
Project6=
Project7=
Project8=
Project9=

[Environment]
UserLevel=2
AdminMode=0
AlwaysShowHeaders=1
SaveEnvironmentOnly=1
DisplayRulers=1
DisplayWasteArea=1
WasteMode=1
WasteLeft=0.5
WasteRight=0.5
WasteTop=0.5
WasteBottom=0.5
LangFile=

[Designer]
GridColor=14737632
DrawGridOnTop=0
SnapToGrid=1
GridStyle=0
FloatPropPrecision=3
ZoomIncrement=25
TapDist=0.01
ShowTapButtons=1
ShowOrderButtons=1
BGTopColor=0
BGMiddleColor=12615680
BGBottomColor=15790288

[Defaults]
GridSpacing=0.1
GridLine=5
ProjectUnitsFactor=1
PaperSize=-1
PaperWidth=8.5
PaperHeight=11

[Printing]
PrintDestination=0
AllowSetup=1
PreviewShadowDepth=5
PreviewWindowState=0
PreviewGridHoriz=0
PreviewGridVert=0
PreviewZoomFactor=100
PreviewZoomInc=10
PreviewMonochrome=0
PreviewGridColor=16776960
PreviewGridPenStyle=0
PreviewRulerType=0

[Toolbar_TZoomToolbar]
FloatLeft=0
FloatTop=0
Visible=1
InPalette=1

[Toolbar_TColorToolbar]
FloatLeft=0
FloatTop=0
Visible=1
InPalette=1

[Toolbar_TLineEditorToolbar]
FloatLeft=0
FloatTop=0
Visible=1
InPalette=1

[Toolbar_TFillEditorToolbar]
FloatLeft=0
FloatTop=0
Visible=1
InPalette=1

[Toolbar_TFontEditorToolbar]
FloatLeft=0
FloatTop=0
Visible=1
InPalette=1

[Toolbar_TAlignmentToolbar]
FloatLeft=0
FloatTop=0
Visible=1
InPalette=1

[Toolbar_TProjectToolbar]
FloatLeft=11
FloatTop=2
Visible=1
InPalette=0

[Toolbar_TDesignerToolbar]
FloatLeft=11
FloatTop=34
Visible=1
InPalette=0

[Toolbar_Graphics]
FloatLeft=0
FloatTop=0
Visible=1
InPalette=1

[Toolbar_BarCodes]
FloatLeft=0
FloatTop=0
Visible=1
InPalette=1

[Toolbar_Standard]
FloatLeft=0
FloatTop=0
Visible=1
InPalette=1

[Toolbar_Report]
FloatLeft=0
FloatTop=0
Visible=1
InPalette=1

[ToolbarPalette]
FloatLeft=249
FloatTop=2
DockList=Graphics;BarCodes;Standard;Report;TZoomToolbar;TColorToolbar;TLineEditorToolbar;TFillEditorToolbar;TFontEditorToolbar;TAlignmentToolbar

[ToolWindows]
LeftWidth=120
RightWidth=120

[ToolWindow_TProjectTreeToolWindow]
Visible=1

[ToolWindow_TPropertyPanelToolWindow]
Visible=1

[Editor]
State=0
Height=702
Width=1136
Left=0
Top=0
PropertyWidth=75
ShowPropertyDesc=1
PropertyDescHeight=79
ShowChangedProps=1
ExcludeNSPProps=1
CustomColor1=12615935
CustomColor2=16512
CustomColor3=4210688
CustomColor4=33023
CustomColor5=8404992
CustomColor6=16711808
CustomColor7=12615680
CustomColor8=8388863
```

Comment: Did you try installing Delphi outside of Program Files (e.g. C:\Delphi7)?

Comment: @Olivier I have not but I will try that now - will post results.

Comment: @Olivier.  I tried installing to C:\Delphi7 - the only difference is the location of the ND_JPEG50.bpl in the error message (C:\Delphi7\Projects\Bpl\ND_JPEG50.bpl) about the TRaveGraphicImage.  The only improvement is that I can remove the ND_JPEG50.bpl entry from Rave.ini and get back into Rave as normal (i.e. I don't have to run D7 as admin)

Comment: @Olivier Do you still have access to your old development computer? Why am I asking this? I have a feeling that your problems is two fold. First part of your problem is that you need to make sure that you have full Read/Write rights for all of the folders that Delphi stores source code and packages packages in. This way Delphi won't be blocked by UAC during compilation. Another problem is that you might not be installing same version of Rave components that you had on old computer, based on the fact that on your new computer you apear to have two different versions of ND_JPEG component ...

Comment: ... You could literally go and copy packages from your od computer to the new one and then install them into Delphi so that configuration on the new computer mirrors the one on the old one.

Comment: Another thing you might want to consider is installing some virtual machine with older OS and then run your Delphi in it. This way you could avoid potential problems that Windows 10 might be causing you for using such old application. Granted debugging application on Windows 10 might become a bit more difficult as you would have to use Remote debugger, but it is doable.

Comment: @SilverWarior:  All the 3rd party libraries I've tried with D7 on Win10 compile and install fine.  The key to this - apart from having full source of the packages - is to install D7 in its own folder (named e.g. D:\D7) on my D: drive.  I never allow any of my Delphi stuff anywhere near Windows' boot drive (I've been burnt too many times over the years by Windows boot drive failures).  Put it all on another drive and it will all work fine - no need for VMs or remote debugging or anything like that.

Comment: @SilverWarior  Thanks for the advice - regrettably the old machine was disposed (there was a gap in my employment between the old machine and new machine).  As for the 2 versions - that was a part of a trial I did.  In the folder where we store the RAVE component there are 2 .bpl files - ND_JPEG.bpl and ND_JPEG50.bpl.  I tried initially (and repeatedly) tried installing ND_JPEG50.bpl and had numerous issues that I worked thru plus the issues listed in the question.  Then I noticed the ND_JPEG.bpl and thought I would try it. (running out of characters so more to come)

Comment: @MartynA and SilverWarior.  I'm not sure about getting a VM installed, but I can certainly ask/try that.  Regrettably the laptop only comes with the one SDD so installing on D:\ isn't an option.  There was nominal improvement in installing to C:\Delphi7 - as noted above.

Comment: It's easy enough to create a D: drive on a WIn10 laptop - you just go to Computer Management |  Disk managment, shrink the C: drive to free up some disk space and then create a D: drive in the freed-up space.

Comment: @MartynA I created the D: drive and installed D7 on D:\ and I'm still getting the behavior noted in the original question (TRaveGraphicImage already exists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that the version of Rave that came with our installation is 5.0.4 which (according to our internal documentation) is known to have some issues.  The resolution, if Rave is already installed (I'm guessing there's a way to not install Rave but our directions don't mention that) is to "Repair" the installation (via "Apps" or "Programs and Features" in settings) and, on the Select Features to install mark Rave as "Do Not Install".  Once you have uninstalled rave use the rave_be_5_0_8.exe installer to install Rave.  Once you have Rave installed you can install the ND_JPEG50.bpl as normal in Rave (Edit->Preferences->Packages) and all is working.  Thanks to MartynA and SilerWarior for their assistance.

Comment: So your problem was conflict between Older Rave Components that got installed with Delphi 7 (if my memory serves me correctly they are part of typical Delphi 7 installation) and newer version that you were trying to install manually.

Comment: That seems to be the case @SilverWarior.